# cnn model for binary classification with 86% val_accuracy always returning 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I created a CNN model for binary classification.
I used a balanced database of 300 images.
I know it's a small database but I used data augmentation.
After fitting the model I got 86% val_accuracy on the validation set, but when I wanted to print the probability for each picture, I got probability 1 for most pictures from the first class and even all probabilities are >0.5, and probability 1 for all images from the second class.

This is my model

```
model = keras.Sequential([
layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[128, 128, 3]),

preprocessing.Rescaling(scale=1/255),
preprocessing.RandomContrast(factor=0.10),
preprocessing.RandomFlip(mode='horizontal'),
preprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=0.10),

layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPool2D(),

layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPool2D(),

layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'),
layers.MaxPool2D(),

layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),])
```

This is the accuracy plot

[image: accuracy plot]

Thank you guys

Comment: what does   image = preprocess_input(image) do, I do not see the code for it?

Comment: @GerryP it's a module from tensorflow.keras.applications.imagenet_utils

Answer (score 1):

I think the preprocessor function scales the pixel values between -1 and +1. However you rescaled your images for training between 0 and 1. try replacing

```
image = preprocess_input(image)
```

with

```
image=image/255
```

see if that works

Comment: It didn't work. from the official documentation of TensorFlow, it says "The images are converted from RGB to BGR, then each color channel is zero-centered with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling.", so I don't think it caused the problem.